# bitwise and operation on multiple binary data in angular js

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I am working on angular js.

I have a doubt on bitwise and operation on multiple binary data(array of binary data["1","100","10000","10"]).

In my HTML page there is a field of multiple check boxes. Each check box has value of 1,2,4,8,16,32.stored in database.
.In my controller for that particular html page,i am converting these to binary data and storing in an array.["1","100","10000","10"]

So if i check on 3 values for the field(for example..1,4,16..), the corresponding binary data array for these values should be performing binary and operation and based on the result i have to store its decimal value in database.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your strings to ints, with `parseInt` and a radix of 2.

Then bitwise `OR` them to pack them into a single integer.

```
var bits = ["1","100","10000","10"].map(function (x) {
    return parseInt(x, 2);
});

var result = bits.reduce(function (accumulator, curr) {
    return accumulator | curr;
});

//result is now 23 which is the decimal representation of binary  1  0  1   1   1
//-------------------------------------------------------------- 16 +0 +4  +2  +1
```

Comment: Now my problem is..based on this result value...how can i bind to the particular field.  For example...the field has 1,2,4,16 values,by adding its 23...based on 23 i should make my checkbox checked for these respective values in the field..Please help me on dis.